# How do i render multiple props in a single component and then pass those props to a child component in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I was trying to render multiple props in a single component both the props are from different apis which are working together and the problem is i want to map the props in a single component to display a list of posts. someone said me do this by creating a variable (array) in my  component. Then, spreading the properties (props) into the variable e.g myVariable.push(...posts, ...externalPosts). But i can't seem to figure out how do i achieve the results the Component  renders another child component called  to which i want to pass on the props.

App.js

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import axios from "axios";
import { Posts } from './components';



const App = () => {
  const [ posts, setPosts ] = useState([]);
  const [ postsExternal, setPostsExternal ] = useState([]);

  const fetchPostsAll = () => {
    axios.get(`http://localhost:2000/posts`).then(({ data }) => {
      let externalPosts = [];
      setPosts(data);
      console.log(data);
      data.map(({ external_id }) => {
        axios
          .get(`http://localhost:2000/posts${external_id}`)
          .then(({ data }) => {
            console.log(data);
            externalPosts.push(data);
          });
        setPostsExternal(externalPosts);
      });
    });
  }

 
  useEffect(() => {
    fetchPostsAll();
  }, []);
  
  return (
    <div>
      <Navbar/>
      <Posts posts={posts} postsExternal={postsExternal} />
    </div>
  );
};

export default App;
```

Posts.js

```
import React from 'react';
import Post from './Post/Post';

const Posts = ({ posts, postsExternal }) => {
    return (
        <main>
            <Container fluid>
                <Row className="p-2">
                    { posts.map((post) => (
                        <Col className="p-lg-4 p-sm-3" key={post.id} xs={6} sm={4} md={3} lg={3} xl={2}>
                            <Post post={post} postExternal={postsExternal}/>
                        </Col>
                    ))}
                </Row>
            </Container>
        </main>
    );
};

export default Posts;
```

Post.js

```
import React from 'react';

const Post = ({ post, postExternal }) => {
    return (
        <Figure>
            <span>{post.title}</span>
            <span>{postExternal.rating}</span>
        </Figure>
    )
}

export default Post;
```

The problem is with the Posts.js file while mapping i want to map both the props and pass those single item props to Post.js

Comment: Unfortunately your explanation is not enough for getting a solution and please start writing a code then share the exact error or problem...

Comment: There is little chance somebody will give you a useful answer without some code. Please include code snippets with what you tried so far.

Comment: @MohammadEsmaeilzadeh i have added the code

Comment: It's still unclear what different props you want to pass on to the `Post` component other than `post` and `postExternal`. These are the only props `Post` is using. Can you clarify?

Comment: yes these are the only two props my mistake

Comment: you should create a component to show post externals, then pass your prop to it and show data

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do:

```
import React from 'react';
import Post from './Post/Post';

const Posts = ({ posts, postsExternal }) => {
    return (
        <main>
            <Container fluid>
                <Row className="p-2">
                    { posts.map((post, index) => (
                        <Col className="p-lg-4 p-sm-3" key={post.id} xs={6} sm={4} md={3} lg={3} xl={2}>
                            <Post post={post} postExternal={postsExternal[index]}/>
                        </Col>
                    ))}
                </Row>
            </Container>
        </main>
    );
};

export default Posts;
```

**Edited:**

```
import React from 'react';
import Post from './Post/Post';

const Posts = ({ posts, postsExternal }) => {
    return (
        <main>
            <Container fluid>
                <Row className="p-2">
                    {posts.length !== 0 && postsExternal.length !== 0 && posts.map((post, index) => (
                        <Col className="p-lg-4 p-sm-3" key={post.id} xs={6} sm={4} md={3} lg={3} xl={2}>
                            <Post post={post} postExternal={postsExternal[index]}/>
                        </Col>
                    ))}
                </Row>
            </Container>
        </main>
    );
};

export default Posts;
```

Make sure your data is loaded.

**fetchPostsAll** function:

```js
const fetchPostsAll = () => {
    axios.get(`http://localhost:2000/posts`)
         .then(({ data }) => {
           console.log(data);

           const externalPosts = data.map(({ external_id }) => {
             return axios
               .get(`http://localhost:2000/posts${external_id}`)
               .then(({ data }) => {
                 return data;
               });
           })

           Promise
             .all(externalPosts)
             .then(externalPosts => {
               setPosts(data);
               setExternalPosts(externalPosts);
             });
    })
    ;
  }
```

Comment: The postExtrenal returns undefined

Comment: Hey @Musaddik Rayat the component wont render after rendering once. It only renders once and then disappears and there are no errors in the console.log

Comment: My data is loaded after an empty array is recevied

Comment: I think it's happening because you are render your component too many times. I've edited your **fetchPostsAll** function. Have a look at it.

Answer (score 2):

You just don't desctructure the props and pass it as is.

```
import React from 'react';
import Post from './Post/Post';

const Posts = (props) => {
    const { posts } = props;
    return (
        <main>
            <Container fluid>
                <Row className="p-2">
                    { posts.map((post) => (
                        <Col className="p-lg-4 p-sm-3" key={post.id} xs={6} sm={4} md={3} lg={3} xl={2}>
                            <Post {...props} post={post}/>
                        </Col>
                    ))}
                </Row>
            </Container>
        </main>
    );
};

export default Posts;
```

And you can do this in your App.js

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import axios from "axios";
import { Posts } from './components';

const App = () => {
  const [ posts, setPosts ] = useState([]);
  const [ postsExternal, setPostsExternal ] = useState([]);

  const fetchPostsAll = () => {
    axios.get(`http://localhost:2000/posts`).then(({ data }) => {
      let externalPosts = [];
      setPosts(data);
      console.log(data);
      data.map(({ external_id }) => {
        axios
          .get(`http://localhost:2000/posts${external_id}`)
          .then(({ data }) => {
            console.log(data);
            externalPosts.push(data);
          });
        setPostsExternal(externalPosts);
      });
    });
  }

 
  useEffect(() => {
    fetchPostsAll();
  }, []);

  const props = { posts, postsExternal };
  
  return (
    <div>
      <Navbar/>
      <Posts {...props} />
    </div>
  );
};

export default App;
```

Comment: Hey @Yadab this is perfect but i am not able to pass the postExternal props to the post component in the Post.js file